# Genexus DBConnection

Tags: genexus

Estoy tratando de conectarme a diferentes DBMS en una misma KB (Genexus 17 U9 .Net)

Para esto estoy utilizando DBConnection y funciona bien. Excepto que solo puedo conectarme a un único DataStore que seria el "Default". Cuando ingreso un DataStore diferente al Default no lo considera y conecta al DataStore Default.

```
Do case
case &DBMS = DBMS.SQLServer
    &DBConnection = GetDatastore("Default") 
    &DBConnection.UserName = 'user1' 
    &DBConnection.UserPassword = '1234'
    &DBConnection.ConnectionData = "DATABASE=dbdemosqlserver" //SQLServer
    
case &DBMS = DBMS.MySQL
    &DBConnection = GetDatastore("DemoMySQL") 
    &DBConnection.UserName = 'root' 
    &DBConnection.UserPassword = 'root'
    &DBConnection.ConnectionData = "Data Source=dbdemomysql"  //MySQL
EndCase
```

En la documentación no he encontrado restricción con respecto a esto.

¿Como podria conectarme a diferentes DataStore definidos en una misma KB?

Saludos.

Comment: Si en el nodo datastore de genexus preferences pones: boton derecho > edit connection e intentas conectarte al DBMS, podes? te da algun error? Probaria ese camino primero para asegurarnos que este todo ok con la config.

Comment: Si, tengo acceso a los 3 Data Store con "Edit connection". Esta todo ok.

Answer (score 0):

Nosotros usamos la propiedad del generador Event Handing | Before connect
Ahi colocamos un procedimiento que recibe inout:&DBConnection.
Y Source:

```
do case
    case &DBConnection.DatastoreName.ToUpper() = "DEFAULT"
        &base = &SdtGlobal.base
    case &DBConnection.DatastoreName.ToUpper() = "COTIZACIONES"
        &base = &SdtGlobal.baseCotizaciones
    case &DBConnection.DatastoreName.ToUpper() = "MASTER"
        &base = 'master'
endcase

&DBConnection.UserName = &SdtGlobal.usuarioBD
&DBConnection.UserPassword = &SdtGlobal.contraseniaBD
&DBConnection.ConnectionData = "Database=" + &base + ";Server=" + &SdtGlobal.servidor + ";"
```

En nuestro caso todos los DataStores son sql server.

Comment: Entiendo, por lo visto solo te puedes conectar a un solo DBMS de forma dinámica con Genexus. Gracias por tu comentario.